# Spring boot can not recognize path of my image

Tags: spring-boot, resources

I have a spring boot program, and in the data loader class that implements commandLiner, I saved a picture of roastedChicken, which it's path that I entered is \static\images\roastedChicken.jpg, and you can see it in detail in the image below. But the program gives an error and says that it does not recognize this path, why?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxnNk.png)

error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-25 23:21:08.892 ERROR 2632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.arbabsoft.recipe.RecipeApplication.main(RecipeApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \static\images\roastedChicken.jpg
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:235) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3206) ~[na:na]
    at com.arbabsoft.recipe.bootstrap.LoadData.run(LoadData.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried switching \s to /s, removing the first slash or putting the picture directly in resources without the static\images directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:static/images/roastedChicken.jpg");
```